# Simplify the summation of $k\cdot \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: summation, combinations

Prove that for $n\geq 2$ 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n2^{n-1}
$$
I have used this summation to make other conversions in the past but I am not sure if/how it can be used in this situation.
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)x^{k}y^{n-k}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combinatorial proof: Say you have $n$ numbered balls, and you want to paint exactly one of them red, and the rest either blue or green. Then there are $n$ ways to pick which one becomes red, and for the rest, there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to paint them all either green or blue. In total there are $n2^{n-1}$ ways to do it.

For the other side, look at $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)! } = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}$ Each term $k\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways to choose $k$ balls to paint green and red. Exactly one of them must be red, and that's the $k$. Then paint all the other $n-k$ blue. As we sum over all $k$ from $1$ to $n$, we range over all possible different choices for how many green plus red balls we should have.

We could also have noted that we have $k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, so 
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)! } = \sum_{k = 1}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
At this point we could just put the $n$ outside, rearrange indices, quote the theorem that says $\sum_{i = 0}^j\binom{j}{i} = 2^j$ and be done. But that wouldn't be combinatorial, now would it?

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** Consider: $(1+x)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k$. Differentiate Both sides w.r.t $x$ and evaluate it at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x = y = 1$ in
$$ n(x+y)^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx} (x+y)^n = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{k}y^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} kx^{k-1}y^{n-k}. $$

Answer (score 1):

No calculus needed.

If
$f_n
= \sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
f_n
&= \sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
\qquad\text{adding the zero valued term for } k=0\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (n-k)\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
\qquad\text{replacing }k \text{ with } n-k\\
\text{adding,}\\
2f_n
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (k+(n-k))\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&= n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&= n2^n\\
\text{so}\\
f_n
&= n2^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

As if often the case
in my answers,
nothing original here.